# Laptop will not post. Need advice

Tags: lenovo-laptop, laptop-repair

My laptop fell on the ground and now it won't post. When I tried to power it on, the power led blinks green and then goes off. I power cycled the laptop by taking out the battery and clicking the power button but no dice. I talked to lenovo tech support and they said I need a new motherboard. Could it be anything else? I just want to double check before I purchase a new motherboard for a relatively old laptop.

Also does anyone know which motherboard I need to purchase for it? Here's the laptop model:
[image]

Comment: Hi, this question would be better on superuser, I voted a move, but you can flag a moderator to move your question too

Comment: A replacement motherboard will likely need to come from Lenovo, anyway, so just ask them what the part number is.  They are likely right because pretty much everything in a laptop is on the motherboard.  If you aren't an experienced technician, or don't have the service manual and required tools, consider letting them do the repair.  However, a better thing to consider is buying a new laptop (and potentially cannibalizing the old one for parts).  1) It looks like your laptop is at least 4 yrs old, which means that other components are approaching end-of-life (cont'd)

Comment: (which might have been hastened by the fall).  So the motherboard may just be the first in a series of replacements that will have you rebuilding the old technology at retail prices.  You may end up paying the cost of a new laptop to keep your old one running a little longer.  2) The replacement motherboard will be a refurbished one with a 90 day warranty, at a major fraction of the cost of a new laptop (with a new warranty).  You may be performing the quality control on the replacement motherboard's repair.  If you have the cash, putting it towards a new laptop will be a better investment.

Answer (score 2):

Laptops should never be fell on the ground because most of the time, it causes the system to completely unstable. Dell techsupport could be right on this initial diagnosis and purchasing a new motherboard for your laptop is almost equivalent to purchasing a brand new one.

Answer (score 2):

Even with a new motherboard, there's a probability that the hard disk will have been damaged in the fall, and the laptop stop won't work.

You probably care more about the data on it than the rest of the PC, so I'd recommend:

1. pull it apart and get the disk out - you can put it back later if you like
2. get a hot-swappable hard disk reader that can read laptop sized disks
3. plug it all together, try to read the disk from another computer
4. if you can read the disk, copy off any data while you can
   Also, this means that it might be worth replacing the motherboard
   If the disk won't mount, then no motherboard replacement will help.
5. {optional - this is what I'd do} Instead of getting a new motherboard decide how much the laptop was worth. If it was an Alienware gaming laptop or equivalent, claim on your home contents insurance and get a new one. If it was a crappy el cheapo then buy a $300 ebay ex corporate laptop for cheaper than the motherboard and hard disk replacement would cost.